# Tridion 2013 install error: A later version of MicrosoftPrerequisitesInstaller is already installed

Tags: 2013, web8

We had SDL web 8 installed on a Windows Server 2012 R2 server with SQL Server 2012 SP2 for the database. We uninstalled Web 8 and are trying to install Tridion 2013, but we are getting the error

> A later version of MicrosoftPrerequisitesInstaller is already installed. Setup will now exit.

during the Content Manager installation.

Does anyone know how to resolve this error?

Comment: did you check all the traces of web8 has gone?
Also, share when you are getting this error - starting the setup or at a specific step of installation

Comment: As Pankaj already suggested, This is happening because your system still holding the information of SDL Web 8. First Uninstall it properly check the prerequisites are completely removed from your machine and then start the fresh installation. Also uninstall the additional products (like .net framework etc.).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SDL suit installs MicrosoftPrerequisitesInstaller as a prerequisite permanently (like IIS or .NET) and does not uninstall together with Tridion. And its version different for different Tridion versions. If you want to uninstall it, you should execute following command from command line (preferably by Administrator):

```
msiexec /x "{EE4E9939-72FC-4F6E-A754-DEE287E7F1F6}" /l*vx C:\temp\log.txt
```

where {EE4E9939-72FC-4F6E-A754-DEE287E7F1F6} is a guid of MicrosoftPrerequisitesInstaller feature installed with Web 8.

Note that this guid depends on Tridion version and will be different in case you firstly installed SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 and then want to install SDL Tridion 2013.

Check C:\temp\log.txt if uninstalling was successful.

Comment: If the GUID mentioned by Stanislav doesn't work, you can use the following PowerShell command to find the GUID:
`get-wmiobject Win32_Product | Where {$_.Name -eq 'MicrosoftPrerequisitesInstaller'}`